# How to rename two different values in same column

Tags: r

```
     Var1   Var2
1     A    High
2     A    High
3     A    High
4     B    High
5     B    Med
6     B    Med
7     C    Med
8     C    Low
9     C    Low
10    C    Low
```

Im trying to create a third column where it takes all the values from var 2 but Med and low is replaced with not High. SO far I have df$var3 <-select(df,var2). Which made the df but cant figure out how to replace the values in column. I was thinking something with select function or replace but keep messing it up. Would really appreciate help right now.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the `%in%` operator here:

```r
df$Var2 <- ifelse(df$Var2 %in% ("Med", "Low"), "Not High", df$Var2)
```

Or, if you want to phrase this as just replacing any value in `Var2` which is not `High` with `Not High`, we could use:

```r
df$Var2 <- ifelse(df$Var2 != "High", "Not High", df$Var2)
```

Comment: I tried the second method but for instead of High in column it was replaced with 2 instead any idea why that happened?

Comment: Please create your data frame using `stringsAsFactors=FALSE`